# What partition needs to be dealt with to get a clean install of windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, malware-removal

I am trying to do a clean installation of windows and I need a bit of help.

I won’t try to explain why I was targeted. The disk has 4 partitions, below there are pictures that explain the current status of my PC. I have a USB boot drive and I need help to make sure it’s clean and malware free.

[image: https://ibb.co/bmN0stL]
[image: https://ibb.co/MZ30D9w]
[image: https://ibb.co/CQ4k1Np]

It seems I’m in hot water, what would you guys do to remedy the situation?

Comment: The image doesn't show any partition layout. In the boot menu you can only see what bootloaders are installed in the ESP, regardless of the system partition of any given OS actually exist (bootloaders are usually kept even when all other partition are removed, hence the answer's suggestion to do it correctly). And before reinstalling I strongly suggest to disable "Legacy support".

Answer (score 4):

You can erase the partition table using tools available on the Windows installation media. **This will destroy all the data on disk.**

Boot from the installation flash drive or DVD. On the screen with the welcome window, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. A command line window should appear.

Type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It may take a few seconds for the program to start.

Type `list disk` and find your disk in the list. Take note of its number. It will probably be `0`. Select it using the command `select disk 0` (use your disk number).

Once the disk is selected, use the command `clean` to erase the partition table. Then type `exit` twice to exit diskpart and the command line.

Windows installer will create a new partition table during the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Use a proper Microsoft Install ISO and Delete All Partitions. The Windows Install will ask this, or if you wish to Keep Nothing.

There is nothing normally and nothing in your list that need to be saved, so delete.

Windows 10 and 11 will create 3 partitions:  UEFI, Recovery and Data.

That is the best way to start.